# Sort results by name & asc order on Archive.php

Tags: archives, sort

I currently use the following code to list posts in Archive.php but I want the results to be ordered by name in ascending order, I have checked the codex but the answer isn't clear to me, how can I get this working?

```
<?php $post = $posts[0]; // ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using custom query in your archive.php can you please show it? may be post the complete archive.php on http://pastie.org and update your answer with the link?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a hook (the `pre_get_posts` hook) to change the order. But you should check that the query is one for which you do want to alter the order! ([`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) or  [`is_post_type_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) should be sufficient.)

For instance, put the following in your theme's functions.php...

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
    function my_change_sort_order($query){
        if(is_archive()):
         //If you wanted it for the archive of a custom post type use: is_post_type_archive( $post_type )
           //Set the order ASC or DESC
           $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
           //Set the orderby
           $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        endif;    
    };
```

Comment: Hi, will you be able to show how does the default ordering works? Some links if possible .thanks

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla WP is developed as a blog, so the sensible/default ordering is by post_date DESC (=descending), so that's newest-post-first. If you're using WP for something where time is less relevant (most types of lists, like your records collection, recipes, a glossary, ...) you'll want to order often post_title ASC (=Ascending, so alphabetic by title with numbers preceding letters).

Comment: Thanks. Works fine for my taxonomy archive page.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Worked but destroyed my menu. There are more queries on the archive page, to change just the one needed, I succeeded with `if(is_post_type_archive($post_type) && $query->query["post_type"]==$post_type)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// we add this, to show all posts in our
// Glossary sorted alphabetically
if ( is_category('Glossary') )  {
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby'        => 'title', 
        'order'          => 'ASC' 
    );
    $glossaryposts = get_posts( $args );
}
foreach( $glossaryposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain _why_ this helps the OP? Please, always add an explanation on top of a piece of code. Thanks.

Comment: The question was Sort results by name & asc order on Archive.php.  Presumably according to the answerer this code will Sort results by name & asc order on Archive.php?

Answer (score 0):

further to Stephen's answer, if you want to just query and order by the title, you could use this in your template file:

```
$args = ( array(
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'title',
 ) );

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Straight from the WordPress code reference - "This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’ action within WP_Query."

Bottom line @Stephen Harris has the correct way of accomplishing this.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/