# Order archive results by post id in custom taxonomy template

Tags: loop, templates, archives

My theme's archive template uses this for the loop,

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Seems to be ordered by post title but I need them ordered by the post id. Just need help with the syntax i think. How do I change the order of the loop list of posts or incorporate this in to the loop? I am researching this but if anyone has a simple solution I would be extremely grateful.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'  => 'ID',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_query ( $args );
```

Comment: taxonomy-places.php is the template, the term is obviously, places

Comment: Found answer here, easy enough, but how do I only apply this function to archive-places? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/sort-results-by-name-asc-order-on-archive-php

Comment: I used this, if(is_archive( 'taxonomy-places.php')):

Answer (score 0):

I used this [Sort results by name & asc order on Archive.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/sort-results-by-name-asc-order-on-archive-php)

changed to select the archive template  if(is_archive( 'taxonomy-places.php')):