# How to change posts order on Category and Tag archives?

Tags: wp-query, loop, hooks, pre-get-posts

WordPress by default order posts in descending order by date. But I want them to be in ascending order by date.

How do I turn the order to ascending only for tags and category? I don't want blog post orders to change.

Comment: Please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/327823/edit) the question giving us information on how do you retrieve posts on these pages.

Comment: Man! I don't understand that much WordPress coding. I have only styled the archive.php no change in function. The post on my categories orders in Ascending and order by date. They are ordered on basis of new dates to older dates. Now, I want them to be in descending.

Comment: Having no coding experience you have to search for a plugin to achieve the goal.

Comment: No problem dude, I found an answer to this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/sort-results-by-name-asc-order-on-archive-php. I put the order to my desire. Answered by Stephen Harris.

Comment: If you are interested in a plugin-like solution: I would recommend any of these two plugins:
[Chronological Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/chronological-posts/) (reverses post order for all category archives)
[Post Order By Category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-order-by-category/) (reverses the post order for a specific category)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify this order. Here's the code:

```
function my_change_posts_order( $query ){
    if ( ! is_admin() && ( is_category() || is_tag() ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
};
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_posts_order');
```

What we do here is:

1. We're adding our function that will modify params for WP_Queries
2. We make sure that it will change only main query (the one created by WordPress) and only on category and tag listings ( `is_category()` and `is_tag()`).
3. We change the order of posts for these pages by setting `order` to `ASC`